# Probability of rolling a six in 4 rolls of a dice

Tags: java

The program I wrote simulates rolling dice and attempts to calculate the probability of rolling a six in 4 rolls. The issue I'm having is it always calculates 0.66 when it should be around 0.50 and I can't figure out why.

```
public class Die {

    int outcome;

    void roll() {
        double x = Math.random();
        x = 1.0 + (x * 6.0);

        outcome = (int) Math.floor(x);
    }
}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float sixesIn4 = 0F;
        int sixesIn24 = 0;
        double sixIn4Probability;

        for (int k = 0; k < rolls; k++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                die.roll();
                if (die.outcome == 6) {
                    sixesIn4++;
                }
            }
        }
        sixIn4Probability = sixesIn4 / rolls;
        System.out.println(sixIn4Probability);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm not much of a statistics guy. But in 4 roles where the chance is 1/6, you would total 4/6 which is 0.66 or do I miss your point?

Comment: You seem to be counting the total number of sixes in all your rolls, not the number of times you rolled at least one six in four rolls. Different.

Comment: That's what I get using the program but the actual probability is just over 0.50

Comment: @Stefan nope that's not how the maths work. The easiest way to calculate it is the inverse of rolling 4 non-6s: `1 - pow(5.0 / 6.0, 4.0)` which is around .52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of rolling at least one six in four rolls is `1-(5/6)**4`, which is just over 0.5.

You are calculating the expected number of sixes from 4 rolls, which is `4*(1/6)`, 0.67.

You just need to increment your count once for each group of 4 rolls. The smallest change, without rewriting your whole code, is to add a break statement in your inner loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        die.roll();
        if (die.outcome == 6) {
             sixesIn4++;
             break;                  
        }
    }
```

That way you only count each group of 4 once, if it has a six in it, instead of counting the number of sixes you get from it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep track of a boolean in each roll to determine if there are one or more sixes. My sample gives 0.526, which given your comments should be (close to) correct.

```
class Die {

    int outcome;

    void roll() {
        double x = Math.random();
        x = 1.0 + (x * 6.0);
        outcome = (int)Math.floor(x);
    }
}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rolls = 1000;
        Die die = new Die();

        float sixesIn4 = 0F;
        double sixIn4Probability;
        boolean sixinRol;

        for (int k = 0; k < rolls; k++) {
            sixinRol = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                die.roll();
                if (die.outcome == 6) {
                    sixinRol = true;
                }
            }

            if (sixinRol) sixesIn4 += 1;
        }
        sixIn4Probability = sixesIn4 / rolls;
        System.out.println(sixIn4Probability);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your code. Firstly, you are generating floating point random numbers and then converting to ints. Better to just generate ints. Secondly you are counting all 6s rolled, not just the sequence of rolls that result in at least 1 six.

Split out your 'at least 1 six' into a separate method:

```
private boolean atLeastOneSix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (random.nextInt(6) + 1 == 6)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then your counting becomes more obvious:

```
int sixCount = 0;
for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++) {
    if (atLeastOneSix())
        sixCount++;
}
double prob = 1.0 * sixCount / trials;
```

If you are comfortable with streams:

```
IntStream.range(4).map(i -> random.nextInt(6) + 1).anyMatch(r -> r == 6);
```

And

```
long sixCount = IntStream.range(trials).filter(i -> atLeastOneSix()).count();
```